# Using Task.WhenAll but each individual Task's success needs to be tracked

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, async-await

The original method is the inefficient `foreach` loop that awaits every job (which is an I/O bound network call):

```
foreach (var job in Jobs)
{
    try
    {
        await DoJobAsync(job); //Pass job to external vendor API
        job.Succeeded = true;
    }
    
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //do nothing, let loop continue
    }
}
```

Now to improve performance, I want to use `Task.WhenAll` to process all jobs in a non-blocking manner.

However, we need to make sure that each `job` object only has that `Succeeded` property set to `true` if the `DoJobAsync` task does not throw exception.

If we do this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(Jobs.Select(j =>
{
    var task = DoJobAsync(j);
    j.Succeeded = true;
    return task;
}));
```

My understanding is that if any job task ends up throwing exception, that property will still get toggled to `true` because each individual task is not awaited as it is created, making the code flow go right past it.

I know I can capture the `Task` returned by `Task.WhenAll` to have access to a list of all exceptions thrown, but I can't figure out a way to use them to trace back to the `job` that threw the exception.

How do I work around this issue?

Comment: Any reason for why you can't just update `DoJobAsync(Job job)` to set the `Succeeded` property to true after the job is done? Then you can just catch an AggregateException and loop over each job to check its `Succeeded`  property.

Comment: Moreover, you could also throw an an custom exception that includes the failing job, such as `JobExecutionException` and just get that from catching the `AggregateException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an async delegate as the `selector` of the [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) operator:

```
await Task.WhenAll(Jobs.Select(async job =>
{
    await DoJobAsync(job);
    job.Succeeded = true;
}));
```

This way each job will be projected to a `Task` that will not be the original `DoJobAsync(job)` task, but instead a wrapper task that encapsulates the logic for updating the `Succeeded` property. This property will be updated immediately after the `DoJobAsync(job)` task completes successfully.

It is possible that multiple `Job` objects might have their `Succeeded` property updated in parallel. It depends on whether a `SynchronizationContext` is installed on the current thread.

Comment: Is this equivalent to creating another explicit wrapper method `async Task WrapJobAsync(Job job)` that wraps `await DoJobAsync(job); job.Succeeded = true;`, then use this method instead of the original to create the task list? Thanks.

Comment: @thankyoussd yes, it's equivalent. You can do it either way, it's personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

Return the result true/false from the method DoJobAsync().

This way you can return the result directly.

```
await Task.WhenAll(Jobs.Select(j =>
{
    return DoJobAsync(j);
}));
```